# DROPLIST DOWN, LOOP WHILE, Foreign key

Tags: php

I would like to display 2 dropdown lists. My 2 dropdown lists are in fact 2 foreigns keys (`fk_candidat, fk_course`). 
I can recover only 1 foreign key for now, which is the `fk_candidat`

Here is a example below

[image]

```
<form action="add_facture.php" method="POST">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Date:</td>
      <td><input type="date" name="dateSaisie" style="width:142px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Candidat:</td>
      <td>
        <select name="fk_candidat" style="width:148px">
<?php
while($row = $sql->fetch()) {
?>
          <option value="<?= $row['id_candidat']; ?>"><?= $row['name_candidat'];?>&nbsp;<?= $row['firstname_candidat'];?></option>
<?php
}
?>
        </select>
    <tr>
      <td>Id cours:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="id_course" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Ajouter"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

My problem is here, how to create the dropdown list for the foreign key `fk_course`?

Comment: Why can't you just repeat what you did with the first one?

Comment: Can you include the section that defines `$sql`

Comment: @ Dharman, I have a problem of syntax. Do you have a example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use foreach?

Try this code inside select tag:

```
   foreach ($row as $key) {
    echo '<option value="'.$key->id_candidat.'">';
    echo $key->name_candidat .' '.$key->firstname_candidat;
    echo'</option>';
   }
```

Then you can repeat that on the other dropdown.